# Bash script for whole sentence to use as file name

Tags: bash, whitespace, quotes, sentence

I'm trying to do a very simple bash script that asks me for a name for a book and then uses that name with the given command. It works fine as long as I don't have any whitespace in names. I thought I could use quotes or something but I just don't get it. Google didn't help me either which was odd as I thought that this would be simple enough for a one minute job.

What I have:

```
echo Give the name of the book:
read varname

pdfsandwich foo.tif -o $varname.pdf
```

Comment: Rule 1: Always run your scripts through https://shellcheck.net

Comment: You must use double quotes to make the shell interpret your variable in the string: pdfsandwich foo.tif -o "$varname".pdf

Comment: Or as it's often put, [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) :)

Comment: @Shawn Thanks! shellcheck.net is amazing. I will definitely use it from now on!